# cannot create a docker container via docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker compose for `nginx` and this is the file

```
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: <private-repo>/nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./myfile.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx-ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - mydir-static:/usr/share/html
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - my-network
```

when i am trying to deploy this file i am getting this error,

```
 ⠿ Container nginx                    Starting                                                                                               0.9s
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim
task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process:
error during container init: error mounting 
"/var/lib/mydeploymentfolder/deployment/myfile.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf": mount /var/lib/mydeploymentfolder/deployment/myfile.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
(via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount 
a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists 
and is the expected type
```

this is myfile.conf

```
upstream my_service {
    server myservice:8086;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.org xx.xxx.xx.xxx xx.xx.xx.xx localhost;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/myfile.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/myfile.key;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location /static {
        alias /usr/share/html;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://my_service;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_service;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It provides a good hint

Comment: i am not able to figure out the error

Comment: Does the file exist that the error message talks about? What does "trying to deploy this file mean"? How is this problem even related to programming?

Comment: yes the file `myfile.conf` exists, i am trying to bring up a docker container

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What does `stat /var/lib/mydeploymentfolder/deployment/myfile.conf` yield on the system that you start the container on?